# VHDL: compare a signal against multiple values

Tags: loops, vhdl, fpga

I want to compare a signal against the list of pre-defined values and check if there is at least equal value it this list (or, alternatively, if there is no equal values in the list).

Example application: compare received command to the pre-defined list of valid commands and go to error state if the command is invalid. Imagine, we have only 3 valid commands: 0x00, 0x01 and 0xFF. Then this code would do the job:

```
--valid commands: 0x00, 0x01, 0xFF

process(clk) is
--somewhere in the middle of FSM
  if cmd /= x"00" and cmd /= x"01" and cmd /= x"01" then
    next_state <= error;
  end if;
end process;
```

But I wonder how to efficiently (*in terms of coding style*) implement the same thing for **longer** lists, without having to manually compare against each value (i.e. avoid writing lines like this:)

```
if cmd=val1 or cmd=val2 or ... or cmd=valN then --imagine N=100
```

I imagine it's something to do with arrays and loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A loop over an array of reference values is probably easier to maintain:

```
subtype ref_value is std_ulogic_vector(7 downto 0);
type ref_value_array is array (natural range <>) of ref_value;
constant ref_values: ref_value_array(0 to 2) := (x"00", x"01",...);
...
next_state <= error;
for i in ref_values'range loop
  if cmd = ref_values(i) then
    next_state <= no_error;
    break;
  end if;
end loop;
```

Comment: There's also a case statement where valid choices for cmd are explicit and all other values are covered by the others choice.

Comment: @user1155120 With a large number of choices this would probably be far less compact and maintainable.

Comment: The choices with no action (next_state not assigned to error) are your ref_value literals separated by '|' instead of ','  No [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is telling here for a lack of context - the meaning of next_state (it's type and use). You've assumed a different value (no_error) than the example in the question. Is it a direct or indirect enumeration value?